# 404 Page Not Found CodeIgniter2 en Host

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estoy tratando de subir una pequeña aplicación que hice a un host (http://fetratel.com/gestionreportev2/) pero por alguna razón, el único controlador que puedo llamar en el 'route.php' es el 'welcome' (el que viene por defecto `$route['default_controller'] = "welcome"`). Cuando le pongo el nombre de otro controlador no lo consigue.

- Probé, usando el nombre del controlador en Mayúscula y me tira 
  "404 Page Not Found The page you requested was not found."
- Probé usando el nombre del controlador en Minúscula y la pantalla aparece vacía.

Mi configuración es la siguiente:

```
gestionreportev2
| application
| | config
| | | config.php
| | | routes.php
| | controllers
| | | export.php
| | models
| | | exportmodel.php
| | views
| | | export
| | | | index.php
|.htaccess
```

config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.fetratel.com/gestionreportev2/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'file');
```

routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "export";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Cabe destacar, que esta misma configuración solo cambiando los parámetros de base de datos para conectarse localmente me funciona perfectamente.

Agradezco todo el apoyo de antemano.

Añado el código del controlador

export.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Export extends CI_Controller {

      public function __construct()
      {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('Exportmodel','ticket');
      }

      public function index()
      {     
            $title = ['title' => 'Listado a Exportar'];
            $this->load->view('Header', $title);
            $this->load->view('Export/Index');
            $this->load->view('Foother');
      }

      public function ajax_list()
      {
            ...
      }
}
```

Comment: Francisco, cabe preguntar lo siguiente. El controlador welcome.php funciona porque dentro tiene una funcion index que CI entiende que debe usar por defecto. Tu controlador export.php tiene una funcion index? O estas especificando a que funcion debe ir en el archivo routes.php?

Comment: Hola Kenny, si posee función Index. Edité el post y añadí el código del controlador que puedas visualizarlo.

Comment: Lo que me temia. Intente tu URL de esta forma 'http://fetratel.com/index.php/gestionreportev2' y si funciono. Hace unos dias con mi equipo de desarrollo tuvimos este mismo problema. Imaginate 3 desarrolladores a tiempo completo tratando de arreglar este bug. No lo logramos. Copiamos todo a una nueva copia de Codeigniter y funciono.

Comment: Entiendo probaré entonces tu sugerencia. De echo yo estaba trabajando con CodeIgniter 3 y me dejó este error.
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONST in /home8/fetrate1/public_html/gestionreporte/system/core/CodeIgniter.php on line 58
Y por lo que leí en internet probablemente la versión del servidor no soportaba la versión de PHP del codeigniter 3. Así que lo bajé al codeigniter 2. Saludos

Comment: Eso es muy probable. Si encuentras una solucion te animo a autoresponder tu pregunta. Saludos y suerte

Comment: Bueno teníamos ese mismo problema, en local funcionaba y en remoto no, el asunto es que pasamos a mayúsculas la primera letra de los archivos controladores y sus llamadas y funciono de maravilla